# mount overlay upperdir under lowerdir?

Tags: mount, docker, overlayfs

I'm new to mounts and overlayfs. Is it possible to put `upperdir` under `lowerdir`? e.g.

```
volumes:
  app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: overlay
      o: lowerdir=${PWD},upperdir=${PWD}/docker/storage,workdir=/tmp/workdir
      device: overlay
```

(I'm copying the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770954/65387))

The reason I want to do this is to keep the data co-located with my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
  phpmyadminvol:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: "overlay"
      o: "lowerdir=${PWD}/ro-data,upperdir=${PWD}/upper1,workdir=${PWD}/work1"
      device: "overlay"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770954/5155484

This did work for me.

Comment: Yeah, but they're not nested like in my question :-) I basically did what you did. Had to restructure my directories, moving all my source code one level deeper.

Comment: Sure, I did TLDR the question and posted what works for me. Sorry for that :)